# Need explanation to one observation with tail utilty

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, tail

I simply tried to tail on a directory using below command, just to see whats happening. I got two different kind of results. Can anyone explain it to me?

1.

```
tail -f -n +1 <testDir>
```

output:

```
tail: error reading ‘testDir’: Is a directory
```

2.

```
tail -f -n +2 testDir
```

output:

```
tail: error reading ‘testDir’: Is a directory
tail: testDir: cannot follow end of this type of file; giving up on this name
tail: no files remaining
```

My concern is why there is a change in output if we use `+1` to `+2` in the command?